# Convert Matrix into a long form Dataset

Tags: import, dataset

I would like to convert a matrix into a dataset.  The structure of the matrix is:

```
  {{"5", "4", "3", "2", "1"},
   {"A", 3, 1, 2, 0, 4}, 
   {"B", 8, 29, 55, 14, 22}, 
   {"C", 15, 87, 418, 728, 340}, 
   {"D", 41, 28, 154, 821, 939}, 
   {"E", 3, 21, 78, 257, 594}}
```

The first nested list are "column" headers, while the first element of each subsequent list are the "row" headers.  The structure of the dataset should be:

```
Column1    Column2    Value
A          5          3
A          4          1
A          3          2

...

E          5          3
E          4          21
E          3          78
E          2          257
E          1          594
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I appreciate all of the responses.  The Wolfram documentation on reshaping lists and building associations from anything other than simple lists is a little bit thin.  Parsing each of these was a good learning experience.  Thanks.

Comment: @Fraccalo This is not a trivial question for both newcomers and experienced WL users. I would forgive OP if he could not come up with anything that works. By the way, **transformations to data long forms are single command one-liners** in R. (With a certain popular, usually preloaded package.) (Also, R-immitaion packages in Python.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov sure, it wasn't intended as an accusation, I apologise if it sounds like it :D I was just asking if he had any kind of code we could have fixed/improved/commented! Then I got too busy and wasn't able to answer the question. Sorry again :)

Comment: @Fraccalo It is fine, the main message of my previous comment is that this should be simpler...

Comment: Concur about using R.  Ordinarily, that is what I would have done but I was trying to learn something new in WL.  Unfortunately, I didn't realize the pool was so deep.

Answer (score 5):

Given:

```
m = { {"5", "4", "3", "2", "1"},
      {"A", 3, 1, 2, 0, 4}, 
      {"B", 8, 29, 55, 14, 22}, 
      {"C", 15, 87, 418, 728, 340}, 
      {"D", 41, 28, 154, 821, 939}, 
      {"E", 3, 21, 78, 257, 594} };
```

Then:

```
Dataset @ Flatten @ Array[
  <|"Column1" -> m[[#+1, 1]], "Column2" -> m[[1, #2]], "Value" -> m[[#+1, #2+1]]|>&
, {Length[m] - 1, Length[m[[1]]]}
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

This code produces the requested long form of the data:

```
data = {{"5", "4", "3", "2", "1"}, {"A", 3, 1, 2, 0, 4}, {"B", 8, 29, 
 55, 14, 22}, {"C", 15, 87, 418, 728, 340}, {"D", 41, 28, 154, 821, 
 939}, {"E", 3, 21, 78, 257, 594}};

data2 = Most[ArrayRules[SparseArray[data[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], Automatic, Null]]];
data2 = data2 /. {r_Integer, c_Integer} :> {data[[2 ;;, 1]][[r]], data[[1]][[c]]};
Dataset[Flatten@*List @@@ data2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
columns = Join @@ Join[Outer[List,m[[2;;,1]], m[[1]]], List /@ # & /@ m[[2;;, 2;;]], 3]
Dataset[Association[{"rowLabel" -> #, "colLabel" -> #2, "value" -> #3}]& @@@ columns]
```

[image]